# Customize vc-mode appearance in mode-line

Tags: mode-line, git, vc

I use `vc-mode` to show information about the current VC state in my mode line, like this:

```
(setq mode-line-format '(… (vc-mode vc-mode) …))
```

However, I find the default format of `vc-mode` pretty verbose.  Notably, it includes the name of the current VC backend, which is not particularly interesting to me—I usually know which VCS the current buffer as, and I don’t really use any VCS other than Git anyway.

How can I customize the appearance of `vc-mode`?  Ideally, I’d hide the name of the backend, and show just the name of the current branch (or probably something similar to `git describe`).

Alternatively, if `vc-mode` can’t be customized, can I somehow get the current branch name from VC, for use in a custom `(:eval …)` construct?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I customize the appearance of `vc-mode`? Ideally, I’d hide the name of the backend, and show just the name of the current branch.

That's pretty much what
[smart-mode-line](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line/) does.
You can give it a try, or you can just copy the advice that it uses:

```
(defadvice vc-mode-line (after strip-backend () activate)
  (when (stringp vc-mode)
    (let ((noback (replace-regexp-in-string 
                   (format "^ %s" (vc-backend buffer-file-name))
                   " " vc-mode)))
      (setq vc-mode noback))))
```

Note that this is a streamlined version of it.
You can find the full code for the advice
[here](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line/blob/007ae4bed22edff2fd2fe4fa1d68c87d50e14ae0/smart-mode-line.el#L1119),
which also applies different faces depending on the state of the
branch.

---

As an alternative, here's an even more streamlined version that
doesn't use an advice.

```
(setcdr (assq 'vc-mode mode-line-format)
        '((:eval (replace-regexp-in-string "^ Git" " " vc-mode))))
```

Comment: That would work—though I'd prefer to use an `:eval` construct instead of an advice—but it's not exactly what I'd call "customising".  It's a dirty hack, isn't it?  I'd treacly prefer a cleaner way…

Comment: @lunaryorn Yes, it's a hack. `vc-mode` is not highly customizable in this aspect (that I can tell). I would prefer a cleaner way too. :-)

Comment: @lunaryorn I've edited the answer to use the `:eval` construct.

Answer (score 4):

I was not happy with the default behavior either. I could never keep the vc info characters straight— ":" for edited, "@" for added, etc. You can feel free to use my method.

I defined several custom faces to display the statuses in various colors. Then I wrote a function to translate the default vc info into a string to insert into the mode line. Then I added a `:eval` line in my mode line definition to show it.

```
;; Define faces.

(defface my/mode:vc-added
  `(
     (  ((class color))
        (:background "#FFAA55"  :foreground "black")  )
     (  t
        (:weight bold :underline t)  )
   )
  "VC status tag face for files that have just been added to
version-control."
  :group 'MY/mode)

(defface my/mode:vc-edited
  `(
     (  ((class color))
        (:background "#F05B80"  :foreground "black")  )   ; "#F04040" maybe?
     (  t
        (:weight bold :underline t)  )
   )
  "VC status tag face for files that are under version control
but which have been edited."
  :group 'MY/mode)

(defface my/mode:vc-in-sync
  `(
     (  ((class color))
        (:background "#60CC60"  :foreground "black")  )
     (  t
        (:weight bold :underline t)  )
   )
  "VC status tag face for files that are under version control
and which are in sync with the respository."
  :group 'MY/mode)

(defface my/mode:vc-none
  `(
     (  ((class color))
        (:background "#70A0D0"  :foreground "black")  )
     (  t
        (:weight bold :underline t)  )
   )
  "VC status tag face for files that are not under version
control"
  :group 'MY/mode)

(defface my/mode:vc-unknown
  `(
     (  ((class color))
        (:background "#FF0000"  :foreground "white")  )
     (  t
        (:weight bold :underline t)  )
   )
  "VC status tag face for files whose version-control status
cannot be determined."
  :group 'MY/mode)

(defvar my-vc-mode-attrs
  '((""  . (" NoVC "  my/mode:vc-none))
    ("-" . (" VC = "  my/mode:vc-in-sync))
    (":" . (" VC > "  my/mode:vc-edited))
    ("@" . (" VC + "  my/mode:vc-added))
    ("?" . (" ?VC? "  my/mode:vc-unknown))
    )
  "Lookup table to translate vc-mode character into another string/face."
)


;; This function helps me understand the version-control status.
(defun my-mode-line-vc-info ()
  "Return version-control status information about the file in
the current buffer, as a fontified string.

The mode-line variable `vc-mode' is nil if the file is not under
version control, and displays a hyphen or a colon depending on whether
the file has been modified since check-in.  I can never keep those
straight.

This function returns \"NoVC\" if the file is not under version 
control.  It displays a string with an = sign if the file is in sync
with its version control, and a string with a > sign if the file has
been modified since its last check-in."
  (let* ((class
          (cond
           ;; If not under version-control
           ((not vc-mode)
            "")

           ;; If under version-control decode the -:@ character
           ((string-match "\\` ?\\(?:CVS\\|Git\\)\\([-:@]\\)\\([^^:~ \x00-\x1F\\\\/]+\\)?" vc-mode)
            (match-string-no-properties 1 vc-mode))

           ;; Otherwise, indicate confusion
           (t
            "?")
           ))

         (branch
          (if (any class '("-" ":" "@"))
              (concat " " (match-string-no-properties 2 vc-mode))
            ""))

         ;; Fetch properties list for the class character above
         (props (cdr (assoc class my-vc-mode-attrs)))
         )

    (concat (propertize (car props) 'face (cadr props))
            branch)))

(set-default 'mode-line-format
   '(
     ...
        (:eval (my-mode-line-vc-info))
     ...))
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like something I really need to copy into my own configuration :)

Comment: where can I get the function `any`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use anything else than GIT as well so i have this advice specific to `vc-git`

```
(advice-add #'vc-git-mode-line-string :filter-return #'my-replace-git-status)
(defun my-replace-git-status (tstr)
  (let* ((tstr (replace-regexp-in-string "Git" "" tstr))
         (first-char (substring tstr 0 1))
         (rest-chars (substring tstr 1)))
    (cond
     ((string= ":" first-char) ;;; Modified
      (replace-regexp-in-string "^:" "⚡️" tstr))
     ((string= "-" first-char) ;; No change
      (replace-regexp-in-string "^-" "✔️" tstr))
     (t tstr))))
```

This would simply look like this to me in my mode-line (I use an [emacs distro](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/src) that supports OSX emojis)  :

[image]